# Tracking thousands of sites with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Our product allows our customer to create websites on their own using a template website builder. For the purpose of this post, just consider our product to basically do what Weebly does. We host all the sites and a customer can point a domain name to our server to have a unique url, for example, mydomain.com or whateverdomain.com.

Our system allows our customer to place his own google tracking ID into a form field which allows the customer to track his site's performance with his own google analytics account. Not all our customers will do this. In addition to allowing the customer to use his own google tracking ID, our company needs to track the performance the sites published on our platform. This has been causing most of the problem for us.

The question is, how should we track the performance of thousands of sites in our network? Some research has revealed that the best way to do this is to use a separate tracking ID for each site. Obviously, this would require us to use multiple accounts and profiles considering that Google limits the number of profiles and accounts allowed. Other research has revealed that it may be possible to use a single tracking ID for all the sites and use dimensions and metrics to separate the sites. This does not seem like the best approach because it would limit our ability to actually run different dimensions and metrics on the sites that we are tracking.

Comment: This question isn't about programming directly and should be moved somewhere like http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Take a look at NewRelic too

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a single tracking ID, you're talking about using [Cross Domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342). The problem is that Google is configured to treat all sites under the tracking ID as a single site when you do this. You would need to use URL parameters or something else in order to pull accurate statistics out (and even then you're going to be limited based on the number of keywords per query on a search engine for example).

The safest choice is to create a custom account for each customer in Google Analytics, that way you can look at their detail individually without worrying about a simple change in your single account wiping out the analytics for all of your hosted sites. Also this will allow you to setup things like Google Webmaster tools to help your individual clients with making sure their websites are optimized.

You might also want to look at building your own integrated custom solution so you can track only the information that you need.